# Show æ, ø, å on a docusaurus page (.md and .mdx files)

Tags: utf-8, markdown, docusaurus, cp1252

Hi I am currently building a docusaurus page and are having some troubles with the letters æ, ø and å.

When i run the code from visual studio code i am able to set the encoding to cp-1252 which is able to render the letters correctly. But when i try to run it from visual studio 2022 with either utf-8 or cp-1252 i just get ?.

I would appreciate any help.